# Are 2 files of the same type with the same number of discrete properties the same size?

Tags: filesystems

Suppose you have 2 uncompressed .RAW image files, each exactly 4096*4096 pixels in size, but one is purely 1 single color (say, #FF0000) and the other contains a segment from the Mona Lisa. The remainder of the properties are all the same.

- Will these 2 .RAW files have the same file size?
- Does this also hold true for 2 .WAV files that contain the exact same sample count (3:00 minutes of 44,100 samples per second) but one is a flat B# and the other is a 3 minute extract from Mozart's Requiem?
- How about 2 .txt files, one filled with 10,000 times the letter `A` and the other the first 10,000 characters from Harry Potter?
- Is there a general guideline for the size difference of 2 files where the same count of data is stored at the lowest granularity (like one pixel, one sample or one symbol, basically the smallest part of the file that can describe all of the variations of the content), but one file has the same data in every part, while the other has a lot of different data?
- Does this depend on the file system?

For clarity, I'm talking about the "actual size". I know that the "size on disk" can make the difference smaller to non-existent.

Comment: Yes to your first three questions. Each byte is simply a number from 000-256. The byte 010 is still one byte in size as well as 222 and so forth.

Comment: If you are talking about actual size rather than "size on disk" then you may as well remove the fifth bullet.  And the fourth seems to say "if each unit of information is the same size, is x * unit = x * unit" which of course is "in all cases, they are same size".

Comment: @paul My train of thought was that a file with most high-value properties would be bigger than a file where most properties were very low, because in the one with high-value properties, thre would be more needed to store each property. Admittedly, I never have to worry about such low-level disk storage metrics.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Then can you clarify (by [edit]ing the question) what you mean by granularity.  The lowest granularity would be the smallest size that can encompass all the variations of the content.  If you are permitting this to vary across different datasets, then clearly you can have a file with zero bytes that can represent infinite zeros.

Comment: @Paul I updated the 4th bullet to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAW files are usually compared to lossy compression formats such as JPEG for images and MP3 for audio. RAW formats retain all information, and are thus lossless.

However, lossless RAW files can be compressed as long as the compression does not lose any data. In your example a RAW file that is all one colour could easily be compressed with something like run-length encoding to a fraction of its uncompressed size. So, the answer to your question is that it depends if the program you are using does compression or not. There is no standard for RAW images, each camera manufacturer does something different.

In the case of WAV files there is almost always no compression, so regardless of the content two files with an equal number of samples will be the same length. Same goes for text files, which are uncompressed Unicode, ASCII or some other encoding.

Filesystems can also implement compression. If the filesystem compresses the data then one file could use less disk space than the other. It depends how compressible the data is.